# Product Reviews is redirecting to shopping cart when i click on "Submit Review Button"

Tags: product, redirect, shopping-cart, review

I am using "rwd" theme in new magento installation, i am facing an issue with product reviews tab in this theme.

When i click on `"Be the first to review this product."` It opens up a form and which i click on `"Submit Review"` after filling up the form it redirects me to the shopping cart page and adds that product into cart automatically. Where as it should give a message that "Your review is awaiting for moderation" and after admin approves the review it should get displayed on the product details page.

Comment: You have call a form write review form under add to cart form that why it goes to cart page

Comment: Thanx for instant reply @AmitBera, But i haven't done any modifications in theme templates files or layout files etc. Its just a new installation.

Comment: Yes, it was called before "Add to cart". You were right @AmitBera, it worked thanx for your time.

Answer (score 2):

As as comment,it was issue with wrong calling for review form at view.phtml file.

There review form block ,is call under add to cart `<form>...</from>.`

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>
....
<?php // $this->getChildHtml('review_form'); /* remove from here */?>

</form>
<?php  $this->getChildHtml('review_form'); //call here  ?>
```

**You need move from there and out below  end**